# c#: get values posted from a form

Tags: c#, forms, post

Im posting some data from another page using a form with the method post. What i would like to know is: Whats the best way to get the values. Going by eacn name in the form as

```
Request["name"]
```

Or is there any way to get a collection of the data and itterate through it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Request.Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), where the `Form` property is a collection of the form values:

```
foreach (var key in myCol.AllKeys)
{
     Response.Write(Request.Form[key]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any smart way to wrap this in an if-statement? So i only do the check if theres a form submitted.

Comment: `if (IsPostback) { ... }` ought to do the trick.

Comment: And how to get the values? Request[item] ?

Comment: I have edited to make it clearer re accessing the values themselves.

Answer (score 4):

You can write

```
foreach (string key in Request.Form)
```

You may also want `if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")` or `if (Request.Form.Count > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

[Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Is the collection of posted key/value pairs.

Comment: I think this is the link you wanted :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx

Comment: Woops, you would be correct sir. Thanks!