# How do you Request[""] with a Dynamic Variable? Request["@Variable"]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, razor, request

I'm building a form, where the number of questions, or inputs on the form varies depending on the value in a database.Each input on the form is a radio type. The name of the tags are dynamic and are loaded from the database using `@db.row.questionID` which would look something like: `<span name=@id>` and equal a value of 1 through whatever queries were requested.

My issue is, i wrote the form using post, and i want to submit the values back into a separate database, but i dont know how to request *multiple* values, that changes dynamically based on query.

Sample code i wrote, it doesnt give me any errors, but it doesnt give me any results either.

```
    foreach(var prow in poll){
        var Question = prow.PollId;
        if (Request.Form["@prow.PollId"] == "A") {                
            int AnsA = row.ResultsA;
            AnsA = AnsA + 1;
            db.Execute("UPDATE Results SET ResultsA=@0 WHERE ResultsId=@1", AnsA, Question);
        }
```

i have also tried:

```
    if (Request["prow.PollId"] == "B") {
            int AnsB = row.ResultsB;
            AnsB += 1;
            db.Execute("UPDATE Results SET ResultsB=@0 WHERE ResultsId=@1", AnsB, prow.PollId);
        }
```

Comment: "@prow.PollId" is a string, if you want to pass dynamic parameters, you must use like Request.Form[Question]

Comment: Interesting post. I didnt take into consideration the quotes being a string value. But then when i switched out with what you said, it gave me an error on submit/post that said `Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.this[string]' has some invalid arguments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to get value in form with dynamic inputs? If yes, you can try this:

```
 NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
 foreach (var item in Request.Form.AllKeys)
 {
        //do something you want.
        // Examble : if(item == "A")// item will return name of input
        // Note: nvc[item] return value of input
 }
```

**Update:**

Request.Form.AllKeys will return all of input name in form.

We use foreach to lopp through colections of input name.

Use nvc[item] or Request.Form[item] to get value of input.

You can read this article :[c#: get values posted from a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739596/c-get-values-posted-from-a-form)

Comment: I was really hopeful for this solution but i am getting a `CS0246` namespace error... something about compiling and not being able to locate reference. Any solutions?

Comment: can you post full page code? On your comment above, error is invalid arguments, maybe has something wrong when you coding.

Comment: Oh, i apologize for that. I was trying to use the `NameValueCollection` and it gave me an error that the reference didnt lead to anything. The `foreach` didnt give any errors, so that worked. But the value isnt storing in database, i wanted to double-check what the `nvc` looked like...

Comment: You should using namespace System.Collections.Specialized or you can use Request.Form[item] to get value of input instead of nvc.

Comment: Okay, sorry for going back and forth, i just require a LITTLE bit more info before i completely understand. i have a radio form, and the name of the input is `1` so when i say `if(item == "A")` that is supposed to mean: `if form.radio.1 value is equal to "A"` or does it mean `if radio on form is named: "A"`? The syntax is working, the code is well written, but the database still has a value of `0`, so nothing is being submitted.

Comment: Oh, uhh, for some reason, i couldnt call NameValueCollection without typing out the whole path that it referenced to. Thanks for listing the path. But the example you wrote gave an error. It's fine though, cause i read the html instead on render, and it was numbered in the names.

Comment: in my examble: if(item=="A") mean if radio on form is named:"A". If you want to check value of input instead name of input, you can use : if(Request.Form[item] == "A").

Comment: Thanks again for help and resources. Everything is working great :D